# what is loadNpmTask and why it is not good

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I know that "`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');`" is not good to use, It is old, instead of, we should use "`require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);`"

I found it because of It results in a unnecessary maintenance, but here I am not crystal clear about what is unnecessary maintenance and why.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/547

Comment: I don't think there is much reason on that, besides less code. https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks